# Pandoc xelatex font-family with relative path

Tags: fonts, xetex, pandoc, markdown

I use Pandoc to generate PDF file from MD file with XeLaTeX engine.

```bash
# in documentation directory
pandoc file.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o file.pdf
```

I've a problem with font-family relative in `YML` part in markdown file.Here you can see files herarchy:

```bash
+-- documentation
|   +-- file.md
|   +-- OpenSans-Regular.ttf
+-- fonts
|   +-- FiraCode-Regular.ttf
|   +-- OpenSans-Bold.ttf
|   +-- OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
|   +-- OpenSans-Italic.ttf
|   +-- OpenSans-Regular.ttf
|   +-- Quicksand-Regular.ttf
```

In `documentation/file.md`

```markdown
---
# ...
mainfont: OpenSans-Regular.ttf
mainfontoptions: 
- Scale=1.1
- BoldFont=../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
- ItalicFont=../fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
- BoldItalicFont=../fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
sansfont: "../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf"
monofont: "../fonts/FiraCode-Regular.ttf"
---

# My document

Content of my document
```

With this configuration **everything works**. But if I want to set `mainfont` with relative path like this:

```markdown
---
# ...
mainfont: "../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
# ...
```

Now, it's **not work** while `sansfont` (for example) works with relative path `sansfont: "../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf"`. I've this error:

```bash
Error producing PDF.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   m
l.19     \setsansfont
```

So I need to place `mainfont` at the root of markdown file when I want to generate PDF file.

Do you know how to use relative path with `mainfont` like other fonts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Oh thanks, I will check this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the path in `mainfontoptions`:

```
---
mainfont: OpenSans-Regular.ttf
mainfontoptions:
- Path=../fonts/
- Scale=1.1
- BoldFont=OpenSans-Bold.ttf
- ItalicFont=OpenSans-Italic.ttf
- BoldItalicFont=OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
---

# My document

Content of my document
```

[image]

Pandoc passes the options directly through to `fontspec`, so you might want to check the manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Of course, thanks *again* for your pedagogy
I didn't know how to accept an answer ^-^''

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exaclty what I was looking for. I figured out that you can also use this to configure your monospace font like this:

`mainfont: SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
mainfontoptions:
- Path=./fonts/
- BoldFont=SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
- ItalicFont=SourceSansPro-It.ttf
- BoldItalicFont=SourceSansPro-BoldIt.ttf
monofont: IBMPlexMono-Regular.ttf
monofontoptions:
- Path=./fonts/
- BoldFont=IBMPlexMono-Bold.ttf`